# Giving all permissions to all users for a database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, permissions

Since the database is created under one user's log in, other users using this computer cannot access this particular database. How can I grant the same privileges to all users who log in to this computer for this database? Step by step instructions through SSMS or by a script will be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 3):

You want local Windows users to have the same permissions as the database owner of a specific database? How about:

- Manually create logins for each Windows account:

```sql
-- repeat this whole block for each user account

USE [master];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [Domain\Account] FROM WINDOWS;
GO

  -- repeat just this portion for each database that account should belong to

  USE [your_database];
  GO
  CREATE USER [Domain\Account] FROM LOGIN [Domain\Account];
  GO
```

- Add the users to the dbo role of each database to which you've added a user account above, using dynamic SQL (uncomment the `EXEC` line when you think it looks right):

```sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
  EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_owner'', N''' + name + ''';'
FROM sys.database_principals
WHERE principal_id BETWEEN 5 AND 16383
AND [type] IN ('U', 'S');

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to give local users access, not necessarily database users.  I might be reading that wrong though.

Comment: @Shark I think you're right, I've made it more complete.

Comment: I agree with that answer.  +1

Comment: I want all local users access rights to this a database.  Can I do this using SSMS?

Comment: Yes, those queries will run in SSMS.

Comment: Does the last snippet need to be run against every database too (i.e. every DB where the new user was added)?

Comment: @AndriyM yes, it does.